# Windows Load Balancer for outgoing traffic

Tags: windows, load-balancing

I have a Java web application providing RESTful API running on 3 CentOS machines. My .NET application running on Windows and I need to invoke the RESTful API running off these 3 CentOS machines.

Does Windows come with a built-in load balancer that allows me to load balance out-going traffic?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could kinda-sorta make it work, but it would be a kludge.

If adding a load balancer pair in front of the API servers is out of the question, I would look at installing a load balancer directly on each CentOS machine, and have them present a common listener address using, for example, keepalived.
The configuration should be similar enough to be easily templated (so you don't need to maintain three separate sets of configurations), and you'd end up with decent availability along with good load balancing for the API without having to resort to ugly hacks. Unless you have wicked amounts of traffic I wouldn't worry much about the additional resource usage from running something like HAProxy on the API servers.